# Authentication Page - UWP app

Tags: uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I am develop a new UWP app, and I want that my first page be an Authentication Page.

But I would like to know if there is any way to manage users. For example, this new application that I am developing will be available in the Microsoft Store (to make the update process easier) but it will be hidden in the store, and I only want 3 to 4 people to be able to access my app so I need an Authentication Page

I want the user to enter a username and password and that this data can be validated, that is, check if they have access to my application. And if so, they can enter the application.

I do not know if I could explain it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the user who can download the app by email id. See the links below

[Managing hidden apps, beta apps and visibility of in-app purchases in Dev Center](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/10/managing-hidden-apps-beta-apps-and-visibility-of-in-app-purchases-in-dev-center/#w3V8XyhI65H8Alph.97)

[Set app pricing and availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability#dist_vis)

How ever you can create a login page if you want. store the details in a database([SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) or [LocalStorage](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/10/getting-started-storing-app-data-locally/#23KUqprvGKG1GLMf.97)) compare the details entered with the stored details. if they match go to first page or else ask for re-enter or exit the app.

Comment: Access restriction based on e-mail id is only applied to Windows 8 users. It won't stop Windows 10 users from installing the app, and they are the audience of UWP.